# BLE Connectivity Issue: My app is working as a Broadcaster and BLE device somtimes does not connect to my app

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

So basically My App is Working as a `Broadcaster`, and the BLE device is the `Central` in our case. So my app advertises and waits for a BLE device to connect to it. However, what's really happening is sometimes the device connects to the app and sometimes not. Sometimes it takes more than 10 minutes, sometimes only 1 minute, and sometimes it just does not connect for as long as you keep it.

One more observation that i have is "I have seen this problem happening much in phones like `Oppo`, `Vivo`, `Mi`". Connectivity issues is not there in `One Plus` phones.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you advertising in the background? What Android version are you using?

Comment: I dont advertise in the background but i keep my android app always just for the testing purpose. Android Version - 11

Comment: What is the advertising interval that you are using? Also, does your app stop advertising and re-advertise after a certain timeout, or is it advertising infinitely? Can you try using nRF Connect on your Android phone to mimic your app and see if the behaviour is the same? You can find the nRF Connect here: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=no.nordicsemi.android.mcp&hl=en_US&gl=US

Comment: Infinite Advertising i guess. I stop advertising on onDestroy or if the bluetooth is turned off. Otherwise it is just advertising.